# Unable to login to Olympus/Restcomm

Tags: restcomm

I am "brand new" to both RestComm and Docker. After some learnings I was able to run Docker (running on an Ubuntu VM - host Windows 10 PRO). Everything appears to be fine but I am unable to login to Olympus (though RestComm console is ok).
The command I am using is: docker run -i -d --name=restcomm -e RCBCONF_STATIC_ADDRESS=192.168.110.162 -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/env_files/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 restcomm/restcomm:latest

Can you guys help me?

Thanks

Cassio